# How to get the difference between consecutive rows in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

```
I have a table in mysql database this data.

id     date         number   qty
114    07-10-2018    200      5   
120    01-12-2018    300      10
123    03-02-2019    700      12
1126   07-03-2019    1000     15

I want to calculate difference between two consecutive rows and i need output format be like:

id     date         number  diff    qty    avg
114    07-10-2018    200     0       5      0
120    01-12-2018    300     100     10     10
123    03-02-2019    700     400     12     33.33
1126   07-03-2019    1000    300     15     20
```

> Any one know how to do this in mysql query? I want first value of diff and avg column to be 0 and rest is the difference.

Comment: What is the logic behind the `avg` column?  Also, what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen avg logic is diff/qty . and latest version of mysql i am using

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For **MySQL 8** then use [Lag](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) window function.

```
SELECT 
    test.id, 
    test.date, 
    test.number, 
    test.qty, 
    IFNULL(test.number - LAG(test.number) OVER w, 0) AS diff,
    ROUND(IFNULL(test.number - LAG(test.number) OVER w, 0)/ test.qty, 2) AS 'Avg'
FROM purchases test
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY test.`date` ASC);
```

**For MySQL 5.7 or lesser version**

We can use the [MySQL variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) to do this job. Consider your table name is `test`.

```
SELECT 
    test.id, 
    test.date, 
    test.number, 
    test.qty, 
    @diff:= IF(@prev_number = 0, 0, test.number - @prev_number) AS diff,
    ROUND(@diff / qty, 2) 'avg',
    @prev_number:= test.number as dummy
FROM 
    test, 
    (SELECT @prev_number:= 0 AS num) AS b
ORDER BY test.`date` ASC;

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Output:

| id    | date          | number| qty   | diff  | avg   | dummy | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 114   | 2018-10-07    | 200   | 5     | 0     | 0.00  | 200   |   
| 120   | 2018-12-01    | 300   | 10    | 100   | 10.00 | 300   |   
| 123   | 2019-02-03    | 700   | 12    | 400   | 33.33 | 700   |  
| 1126  | 2019-03-07    | 1000  | 15    | 300   | 20.00 | 1000  |
```

Explaination:

- `(SELECT @prev_number:= 0 AS num) AS b`
  we initialized variable *@prev_number* to zero in FROM clause and joined with each row of the *test* table.
- `@diff:= IF(@prev_number = 0, 0, test.number - @prev_number) AS diff` First we are generating difference and then created another variable **diff** to reuse it for average calculation. Also we included one condition to make the diff for first row as zero.
- `@prev_number:= test.number as dummy` we are setting current **number** to this variable, so it can be used by next row.

**Note**: We have to use this variable first, in both **difference** as well as **average** and then set to the new value, so next row can access value from the previous row.

You can skip/modify `order by` clause as per your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

There could be better ways to do this, but try this:

```
SELECT A.id,
       A.date,
       A.number,
       A.qty,
       A.diff,
       B.avg
FROM
(SELECT *, abs(LAG(number, 1, number) OVER (ORDER BY id) - number) AS 'diff'
FROM table) AS A
JOIN
(SELECT *, abs(LAG(number, 1, number) OVER (ORDER BY id) - number)/qty AS 'avg' FROM table) AS B
ON A.id = B.id;
```