# Getting top 5 results based on difference from last day data

Tags: mysql

I am running a mysql - `10.1.39-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary`- database.

I am having the following table:

```
| id   | date                | api_endpoint | ticker | open      | high      | low       | close     | volume    |
|------|---------------------|--------------|--------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| 18   | 2019-08-07 00:00:00 | daily        | AAPL   | 195.41000 | 199.56000 | 193.82000 | 199.04000 | 33364400  |
| 19   | 2019-08-06 00:00:00 | daily        | AAPL   | 196.31000 | 198.07000 | 194.04000 | 197.00000 | 35824800  |
| 20   | 2019-08-05 00:00:00 | daily        | AAPL   | 197.99000 | 198.65000 | 192.58000 | 193.34000 | 52393000  |
| 21   | 2019-08-02 00:00:00 | daily        | AAPL   | 205.53000 | 206.43000 | 201.62470 | 204.02000 | 40862100  |
| 44   | 2019-08-01 00:00:00 | monthly      | AAPL   | 213.90000 | 218.03000 | 206.74000 | 208.43000 | 54017900  |
| 5273 | 1999-09-07 00:00:00 | monthly      | AAPL   | 73.75000  | 77.93800  | 73.50000  | 76.37500  | 246198400 |
```

I am calculating returns using mysql:

```
SELECT *
      ,(CLOSE - (SELECT (t2.close)
                 FROM prices t2
                 WHERE t2.date < t1.date
                 ORDER BY t2.date DESC
                 LIMIT 1 ) ) / (SELECT (t2.close)
                                FROM prices t2
                                WHERE t2.date < t1.date
                                ORDER BY t2.date DESC
                                LIMIT 1 ) AS daily_returns
FROM prices
```

The above query adds a column `daily_returns` to my table.

I would like to get the `top 5 highest daily_returns`. I tried to use `ORDER BY`, however, this does not work with a *calculated column*.

Any suggestions how to get the top 5 highest `daily_returns`?

Comment: What is `ORDER BY daily_returns LIMIT 5` giving you?

Comment: Can you explain how this `daily returns` is calculated(as a concept), so if possible we can rewrite query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the difference between consecutive rows in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57613990/how-to-get-the-difference-between-consecutive-rows-in-mysql)

Comment: "this does not work with a calculated column" - [not true](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jLQctoFCt2tUDNTxuNa2x4/0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Update: MySQL 8***

```
SELECT 
    prices.*, 
    prices.close - LAG(prices.close) OVER w AS daily_return
FROM prices
WHERE api_endpoint = 'daily'
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY prices.`date` ASC)
ORDER BY daily_return DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

***MySQL 5.7 & Lower***

Use [MySQL variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) to store `close` value of last day. Compare it with `close` value to the current row to do the calculation.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        prices.*,
        (`close` - @old_close) / @old_close AS daily_return, -- Use @old_case, currently it has value of old row, next column will set it to current close value.
        @old_close:= `close`    -- Set @old_close to close value of this row, so it can be used in next row
    FROM prices,
    (SELECT @old_close:= 0 as o_c) AS t -- Initialize old_close as 0
    WHERE api_endpoint = 'daily'
    ORDER BY `date` ASC         -- return is calculated based on last day close, so keep it sorted based on ascending order of date
) AS tt
ORDER BY daily_return DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Reference: [How to get diff between two consecutive rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57613990/how-to-get-the-difference-between-consecutive-rows-in-mysql/57617753#57617753)

Comment: @Anna.Klee, verify whether it works for you or not.

Comment: Thx for your reply! Would also like to get all columns from the table `prices`. Any suggestions why I only get some columns, based on your query?

Comment: You have to select them in inner query and then in outer query. See my updated answer.