# Nest new column into a Select query

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1

I have the following table that I cannot edit called connector_meter_value:

```
+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------+
| transaction_pk | value_timestamp     | value       | unit |
+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------+
|              1 | 2020-01-24 11:50:19 | 1690.100    | kWh  |
+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------+
|              1 | 2020-01-24 12:00:01 | 1691260.000 | Wh   |
+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------+
|              1 | 2020-01-24 12:00:01 | 7382.430    | W    |
+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------+
|              1 | 2020-01-24 12:30:00 | 1694940.000 | Wh   |
+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------+
|              1 | 2020-01-24 12:30:00 | 7385.140    | W    |
+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------+
|              2 | 2020-01-30 20:18:29 | 1701.680    | kWh  |
+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------+
|              2 | 2020-01-30 20:30:01 | 1703070.000 | Wh   |
+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------+
|              2 | 2020-01-30 20:30:01 | 7424.300    | W    |
+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------+
|              2 | 2020-01-30 21:00:00 | 1706660.000 | Wh   |
+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------+
```

I would like to create the following view that gives me the difference between value per transaction_pk (cum_kWh), but first of all creates a new column that edits the value based on the unit (kWh). I also need to remove rows, such as unit = 'W'

```
+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------+----------+---------+
| transaction_pk | value_timestamp     | value       | unit | kWh      | cum_kWh |
+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------+----------+---------+
|              1 | 2020-01-24 11:50:19 | 1690.100    | kWh  | 1690.100 | 0       |
+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------+----------+---------+
|              1 | 2020-01-24 12:00:01 | 1691260.000 | Wh   | 1691.26  | 1.16    |
+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------+----------+---------+
|              1 | 2020-01-24 12:30:00 | 1694940.000 | Wh   | 1694.94  | 3.68    |
+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------+----------+---------+
|              2 | 2020-01-30 20:18:29 | 1701.680    | kWh  | 1701.680 | 0       |
+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------+----------+---------+
|              2 | 2020-01-30 20:30:01 | 1703070.000 | Wh   | 1703.07  | 2.39    |
+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------+----------+---------+
|              2 | 2020-01-30 21:00:00 | 1706660.000 | Wh   | 1706.66  | 3.59    |
+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------+----------+---------+
```

the kWh column takes the Wh value and divides by 1,000 to create a kWh value that can then be used in the cum_kWh column calculation.

I used the following code when i could edit the connector_meter_value table (i actually duplicated it and edited the duplicated table (which i called meter_value_kWh))

```
CREATE VIEW kWhcharging AS
select t.*,
   COALESCE(kWh - (select kWh
              from meter_value_kWh t2
              where t2.value_timestamp < t.value_timestamp AND t2.transaction_pk = t.transaction_pk
              order by t2.value_timestamp DESC
              limit 1
             ),0
   ) as cum_kWh
from meter_value_kWh t
WHERE value <>0 and t.transaction_pk <>'NULL' and unit<>"W"
```

This worked very well, but because the duplicated table doesn't automatically refresh when the original table does i've tried to create a view of the original table.

I'm now trying to insert a 'kWh' column into the query that is then used to calculate the cum_kWh column, but i can't figure out where to put the line. The starred section below is what I have added

```
select t.*,
   COALESCE(**select IF(unit = 'Wh', value/1000, value) as kWh
            From stevedb.connector_meter_value k1** - 
                   (select k1.kWh
                   FROM stevedb.connector_meter_value t2
                   where t2.value_timestamp < t.value_timestamp AND t2.transaction_pk = 
t.transaction_pk
                   order by t2.value_timestamp DESC
                   limit 1
                ),0
   ) as cum_kWh
from connector_meter_value t
WHERE t.value <>0 and t.transaction_pk <>'NULL' and t.unit<>"W"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the difference between consecutive rows in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57613990/how-to-get-the-difference-between-consecutive-rows-in-mysql)

Comment: @JitendraYadav unfortunately not as I can't use lag in my version of mysql. Progman's answer below almost answers my question though. Thank you

Comment: Oh in that, below section also shows you how to do that in mysql lower version. Let me give you an answer for that

Comment: @RDC_Green Please [edit] your question to include the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` statements for your original data, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Progman the original data comes from an external source (a charge point). I have edited the question to give a fuller picture of the original table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the problem is on how you add a new column to your view, as you already have added the new column `cum_kWh` to your view. When you want to have the value `IF(unit = 'Wh', value/1000, value)` as a new column you simply add it to your view the same way:

```
CREATE VIEW kWhcharging AS
SELECT
    t.transaction_pk,  -- |
    t.value_timestamp, -- | The columns from the original table
    t.value,           -- |
    t.unit,            -- |
    IF(unit = 'Wh', value/1000, value) as kWh, -- The new normalized column 'kWh'
    COALESCE(IF(unit = 'Wh', value/1000, value) - (select
                IF(unit = 'Wh', value/1000, value)
            from connector_meter_value t2
            where
                t2.value_timestamp < t.value_timestamp AND
                t2.transaction_pk = t.transaction_pk AND
                t2.unit != 'W'
            order by
                t2.value_timestamp desc
            limit 1
           )
       , 0) as cum_kWh -- The cumulative calculation
FROM
    connector_meter_value t
WHERE
    unit != 'W'
```

You can also create two views. One view with the additional normalized column `kWh` and the second view, which uses the first view, to calculate the `cum_kWh` value, but has access to the new `kWh` column from the first view.

This will generate the following result table:

```
+----------------+---------------------+---------+------+--------------------+--------------------+
| transaction_pk | value_timestamp     | value   | unit | kWh                | cum_kWh            |
+----------------+---------------------+---------+------+--------------------+--------------------+
|              1 | 2020-01-24 11:50:19 |  1690.1 | kWh  | 1690.0999755859375 |                  0 |
|              1 | 2020-01-24 12:00:01 | 1691260 | Wh   |            1691.26 |  1.160024414062491 |
|              1 | 2020-01-24 12:30:00 | 1694940 | Wh   |            1694.94 | 3.6800000000000637 |
|              2 | 2020-01-30 20:18:29 | 1701.68 | kWh  | 1701.6800537109375 |                  0 |
|              2 | 2020-01-30 20:30:01 | 1703070 | Wh   |            1703.07 | 1.3899462890624363 |
|              2 | 2020-01-30 21:00:00 | 1706660 | Wh   |            1706.66 | 3.5900000000001455 |
+----------------+---------------------+---------+------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you @Progman. This almost works, but now my cum_kWh column is not returning the difference between the rows after the first two rows of data. Like you say it may be easier to create a new view. I was worried that they would not automatically refresh though

Comment: I can see why this is happening now. In my original query I had a Where clause that removed unwanted columns. When I add this where clause to your answer it doesn't remove the rows before making the calculation

Comment: It seems to hide the rows I don't want, but still subtract from them.

Comment: @RDC_Green This view is returning the data from your question in the result table you have written in your question. If you have different data which create the wrong result table, please edit your question to include the source data (as `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` statements, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) and the result table you want.

Comment: sorry @Progman, i didn't see that you had edited your answer. That works perfectly. Thank yoy very much for your help. I have taken some learnings from this for another query I have too.

Answer (score 0):

As already provided you the [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57613990/how-to-get-the-difference-between-consecutive-rows-in-mysql/57617753#57617753). But for your problem you can use two user defined variable.

- First set both variable to zero.
- Now if `transaction_pk` is same for current and old record then find the diff between `value` column, if not set it to zero.
- Set both variable to current row data, so can be used in next row.
- It works on `order by` clause that is must to make sure it works fine.

Note: this solution is only for mysql lower version than 8. If mysql 8 use window function `LAG` for the same.

```
SELECT
    transaction_pk,
    value_timestamp,
    `value`,
    unit,
    ROUND(IF( transaction_pk = @old_tran, IF(unit = 'kWh', `value`, `value` / 1000) - @old_value, 0), 3) AS cum_kwh,
   @old_value:= ROUND(IF(unit = 'kWh' && @old_tran:= transaction_pk, `value`, `value` / 1000), 3)  AS Kwh
FROM connector_meter_value,
(SELECT @old_tran:= 0 AS tran, @old_value:= 0 AS o_val) AS b
WHERE unit <> 'W'
ORDER BY transaction_pk, value_timestamp
```

See the working [Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uiBYRB8MiLxYPju6HAqF4L/2) for the same.

Comment: unfortunately this did not work for me @JitendraYadav Progman's answer is much better. Thank you for your help though

Comment: thank you, I agree the fiddle works, but when i enter into sql in phpmyadmin it has an error line under 'dummy'

Comment: sorry Jitendra, i've updated the question as i was missing some information. As part of my query i remove unwanted rows. I then want the calculation of Wh to happen on the remaining rows

Comment: Check my updated answer and its fiddle in answer itself.